# Is there a way to get the average time if the data is in dd:hh:mm:ss?

Tags: excel

I have a column of data which I need to get the average of and the data is typed in as so: dd:hh:mm:ss .

The format of this column is General so I changed it to Time and tried using the average() formula on the data but no luck either - this gave me #DIV/0!

I want the Average formula to return the average time in the format dd:hh:mm:ss

Comment: `dd:hh:mm:ss` is not a format that Excel will naturally read as a date/time and as such it is stored as a string.  You will need to parse the string first then take the average.

Comment: @ScottCraner Hey! What do you mean by parse the string?

Comment: Tear it apart using Left/Right/Mid to its parts, convert them to the proper numbering system so Excel can read it as date/time.

Comment: Convert to seconds, average then re-convert.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this formula :

```
=TEXT(AVERAGE(INDEX(LEFT(A1:A4, 2) + RIGHT(A1:A4, 8),)), "dd:hh:mm:ss")
```